# How to get and set authorization token for calls when Circuit Breaker is enabled?

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

When I turn Circuit Breaker on I'm getting authentication problems from my services, because authorization token is not present in headers of request.

I found in the web that Circuit Breaker runs on secondary thread, that doesn't has spring security context.

For hystrix, the solution I found is to use shareSecurityContext=true config option, and implement a request interceptor that get the token and set for request.

But, for resilience4j, I not found a solution.

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you find an answer for this? I have the very same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resilience4j circuit breaker itself does not spawn a new thread. But when used with Bulkhead, then code runs within a new thread.
i am assuming you are using Bulkhead with you CB. in that case you can use `ContextPropogator`

For e.g.

```
public class SpringSecurityContextPropagator implements ContextPropagator<SecurityContext> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Optional<SecurityContext>> retrieve() {
        return () -> Optional.of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<SecurityContext>> copy() {
        return (context) -> context.ifPresent(SecurityContextHolder::setContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Consumer<Optional<SecurityContext>> clear() {
        return (context) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
}
```

then configure this in bulkhead config

```
  resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead:
  configs:
    default:
      maxThreadPoolSize: 10
      coreThreadPoolSize: 10
      queueCapacity: 15
      contextPropagators:
        - com.cobalt.cdservice.resilience4j.SpringSecurityContextPropagator
```